# react-native-svg Color Prop Testing

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-svg

I'm currently using `react-native-svg` and the SvgXml component like this:

```
<SvgXml
    xml={ iconXml }
    color={ "#DF2530" }
    height={ 22 }
    width={ 22 }
    testID="testId"
/>
```

When I'm doing my tests using jest and the `toHaveProp`, the color is being converted to `4292814128`. I would assume that it's just a decimal color, but when I convert the hex using `parseInt("DF2530", 16)` I get `14624048` which is way off.

How do I test that the color is the expected one? E.g, the below is what I was expecting.

```
const iconSvg = getByTestId("testId");
expect(iconSvg).toHaveProp("color", "#DF2530");
```

but I'm getting the below:

```
    Expected the element to have prop:
      color=14624048
    Received:
      color=4292814128
```